# select,option и скрытое поле

Tags: html, jquery

Есть форма

```
    <select id="test" name="scat">
    <option value="">Выберите...</option>
    <option value="69">Тест1</option>
    <option value="106">Тест2</option>
<option value="72">Тест3</option>
<option value="105">Тест4</option>
<option value="">Тест5</option>
</select>
```

и есть два скрытых поля

```
<input name="cp_id_483" type="hidden" value="Продажа" id="test" />
<input name="cp_id_369" type="hidden" />
```

Вопрос! Как сделать, если выбрал option тест5, эти два скрытых поля использовались, а если не выбран option тест5, то и не делать к ним запрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью jQuery можно это сделать и атрибута `disabled`, нужно когда выбирают тест5 выдавать атрибуты disabled на нужные вам инпуты и они не попадут в запрос, иначе убираем их, код будет примерно такой, т.к. дали часть HTML не могу сделать рабочий вариант кода, но выглядеть он будет вот так:

```
$(document).on('change', '.selector', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('input[name=cp_id_483]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('input[name=cp_id_369]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('input[name=cp_id_483]').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('input[name=cp_id_369]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Замените селекторы и значения на свои если не будет работать

Comment: мне нужно наоборот, чтоб при выборе тест5, снимался атрибут disabled, и выдавался атрибут selected

Comment: Какой ещё selected на инпутах?

Comment: у меня два input скрытых, при нажатии кнопки отправить, запрос к этим кнопкам идет, а мне нужно чтоб они были disabled, а вот когда выбрал option тест5, тогда они активировались

Comment: Тогда if else местами поменять и по умолчанию дать этим инпутам disabled

Comment: Сделал, теперь к ним вообще запроса не идет, даже когда выбрать тест5

Comment: $(document).on('change', '.selector', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('input[name=cp_id_483]').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('input[name=cp_id_369]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('input[name=cp_id_483]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('input[name=cp_id_369]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});

Comment: Я же сказал заменить селекторы и $(this).val() возможно нужно ровнять не к пустой строке, а реальному значению, вы же дали кусок формы, я не могу угадать что там ещё есть